# Need help converting a traditional polling function to a long polling function

Tags: jquery, cordova, polling, long-polling

I am not too familiar with polling in general, but I need to convert this traditional poll to a long poll.  Also, if there is activity, I want to reset the time and keep the connection open.

```
function startchat(mynumber, incoming){
       
var poll_xhr;
         
(function poll() {
     poll_xhr = setInterval(function() {    
                 $.ajax({
                url: "myurl.php?callback=?",
                type: "GET",
                data: {mynumber: mynumber, incoming: incoming},
                dataType: "jsonp",
                crossDomain: true,              
                success: function (data, status) {

                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var obj = data[i];
                 //a bunch of non-relevant dynamically loaded stuff here 
    
            });
        //poll timer
        }, 10000);
 })();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You  are talking about WebSockets here (long polling) . This cannot be done with jQuery.
Read more [here](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/websockets-and-long-polling-in-javascript-ruby-and-python/)

Comment: no, I need to use a long polling not web sockets. I am on a shared server.

Comment: There is no real long polling with Ajax requests. You just use an interval. You can also use a promise and resolve it in an interval, see https://javascript.info/long-polling